# Combining a raytraced scene with a rasterized scene in DirectX11

Tags: graphics, directx, raytracing

I currently have two scenes in directX11, one using rasterization and the other uses raytracing via a full screen quad in the pixel shader. I'm trying to combine the two while preserving correct depth information but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

I suspect the process will be something like

1. Render the raytraced scene and output two textures in the pixel shader, one depth (using SV_DEPTH) and one colour.
2. Apply the both of the outputs from step one as the active colour and depth targets and render the rasterized scene.

Does anybody know how or have any links regarding the subject.

Comment: Basically you answered your own question, that's pretty much the way to do it. Also your order is right since rendering the rasterized scene after will maximize early depth rejection :) Just make sure that raytracer outputs depth into the normalized 0-1 range and you're ready to go